# SQL statement DateTime format

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am looking for some help in regards to the format that I want my data outputted.

Below is a snippet of the code I am using. It is currently converting the value from the database in seconds and outputting it like

> 1d 12:05:52

I want it to output the information so it calculates the day in the hours, so basically dropping the '1d' like below

> 36:05:52

```
CAST(FLOOR([Running] / 86400) AS VARCHAR(10))+'d ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, [Running], '19000101'), 8) AS [Running]
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction using the code above?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you can use TimeSpan object called test for example and then string.Format("{0:00}:{0:00}:{0:00}",test.TotalHours,test.Minutes,test.Seconds);... hope this will help you

Comment: Just to make sure: Are you looking to convert the SECONDS, or the day + hours? And are you looking for a solution in SQL-side or with VB?

Comment: Currently the data in the table 'Running' is in seconds. It is currently converted to the format '1d 12:05:52'. I want to drop the 1d and get it to calculate the day within the hours, such as '36:05:52'. I am using the SQL statement within my vb project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN [Running]/3600 <= 9 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Running]/3600)+':'+
    RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),([Running]%3600)/60),2)+':'+
    RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),[Running]%60),2) AS [Running]
```

I tested it using this:

```
DECLARE @Running int
SET @Running = 60*60*24*30 + 60*3 + 3 -- should output 720:03:03
SELECT
    CASE WHEN @Running/3600 <= 9 THEN '0' ELSE '' END +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Running/3600)+':'+
    RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(@Running%3600)/60),2)+':'+
    RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@Running%60),2) AS [Running]
```

Output:

```
Running
----------------
720:03:03

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for your help. Is there anyway to make the format HH:MM:SS? At the moment, when there is no hours, it displays H:MM:SS e.g. 0:11:53. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Updated the answer and added a "CASE WHEN" to append a leading zero if necessary.

Comment: Thank you so so much, you have helped me out a great deal. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

As @Hadi said in his comment, you can use the TimeSpan object in VB.Net (you've tagged the question with this so it seems reasonable to suggest), but you could also use this bit of SQL instead, which I think is slightly simpler than the other suggestion :

```
CAST(CAST(FLOOR([Running] / 3600) AS INT) AS VARCHAR) + 
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(SECOND, [Running], '1900-01-01'), 108), 6) as [Running]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more way to do it, good answers here already tho. :)

```
-- Setting param for testing purposes, replace this with actual column in the formula below
DECLARE @SECS INT
SET @SECS = 3787*26

-- Your original formula for 'D' value
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(@SECS / 86400) AS VARCHAR(10))+'d ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, @SECS, '19000101'), 8)

-- New one for HH:MM:SS
SELECT CAST(@SECS/3600 AS VARCHAR(20))+':'+RIGHT('0'+CAST((@SECS%3600)/60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+':'+RIGHT('0'+CAST(@SECS%60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```